# Manejo de cadenas con números

Tags: c

El programa debe pedir una cantidad indefinida de números y debe parar cuando se ingrese un `0`, la duda es porque al guardar un `0` en `num[f]` no deja de pedir números, no se si estoy usando de modo correcto los datos string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
int f, i, a, r, b, c, d, e;
char num[f];

f=0;
b=0;
c=0;

do
{
    f=f+1;
    printf("Dame un numero:  ");
    scanf("%s",&num[f]);

    if(num[f]>0)
    {
        b=b+num[f];
    }
    else
    {
        c=c+num[f];
    }

}
while(0!=num[f]);

for(i=1;i<f+1;i++)
{
  e=num[f]%2;

    if(e==0)
    {
        printf("%d",num[f]);
        printf("par");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",num[f]);
        printf("impar");
    }
}

printf("Suma de positivos:  ");
printf("%d\n\n",b);

printf("Suma de negativos:  ");
printf("%d\n\n",c);

r=b-c;
printf("diferencia");
printf("\n\n%d",r);

}
```

Comment: ¿ Porqué no usas **memoria dinámica** para almacenar los números introducidos por el usuario ? O eso, o preguntas al principio cuantos números se van a introducir. **No puedes** declarar una formación de tamaño infinito O_o

Answer (score 1):

```
int f;
char num[f];
```

Estás creando un array en la pila del programa. Dado que está en la pila **no puede redimensionarse**.

Además, dado que `f` no está inicializado... el valor que contiene es indeterminado, luego estás creando un array de tamaño desconocido... ¿Y qué pasaría si `f` tuviese un valor negativo?

Además, ya para finiquitar esta solución, dado que `f` es una variable, lo que pretendes crear se denomina *VLA* (Variable Length Array) y es una característica no soportada por el estándar desde C99 (allá por 1999), luego en caso de funcionarte, no será portable.

Pues bien, ¿soluciones? Muy sencillo, nadie te está diciendo que tengas que guardar todos los números, luego no hay necesidad de usar arrays ni memoria dinámica:

```
int numero;
int positivos = 0;
int negativos = 0;
do
{
    printf("Dame un numero:  ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    if(numero>0)
    {
        positivos += numero;
    }
    else if( numero < 0 )
    {
        negativos += numero;
    }

    printf("%d",numero);
    if( numero % 2 == 0 )
    {
        puts("par\n");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("impar\n");
    }
}
while(numero != 0);

printf("Suma de positivos:  ");
printf("%d\n\n",positivos);

printf("Suma de negativos:  ");
printf("%d\n\n",negativos);

int diferencia = positivos - negativos;
printf("diferencia");
printf("%d\n\n",diferencia );
```

Comment: Se ha perdido una funcionalidad por el camino: el listado de números pares e impares.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster cierto, un lapsus

Answer (score 1):

> El programa debe pedir una cantidad indefinida de números

Si necesitas almacenar una cantidad indefinida de números, tienes dos opciones:

1. Crear una formación con espacio suficiente como para que quepa una cantidad de números "*indefinida*".
2. Crear una formación con espacio para una cantidad de números arbitraria y redimensionar dicha cantidad cuando sea necesario.

Voy a centrarme en la segunda.

---

Puedes crear una formación solicitando memoria con [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) (**M**emory, **ALLOC**ation, alojamiento de memoria):

```
int cantidad = 100;
int *numeros = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * cantidad);
```

Si en algún momento la cantidad de elementos de la formación se te queda corta, puedes realojar la memoria con [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) (**REALLOC**ation, realojar):

```
numeros = realloc(numeros, cantidad *= 2);
```

Así pues, tu código podría quedar así:

```
int cantidad = 10;
int indice = 0;
int *numeros = (int*)malloc(cantidad);

for (int numero = 1; numero; ++indice)
{
    if (indice == cantidad)
    {
        numeros = (int*)realloc(numeros, cantidad *= 2);
    }

    printf("Dame un numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    numeros[indice] = numero;
}
```

Quisiera resaltar los siguientes cambios que he hecho a tu código:

- Nombres de variables autoexplicativos: la variables cuyo nombre es una sola letra pueden ser adecuadas en ámbitos pequeños y localizados, más aún si dicha letra guarda una relación con la misión de la variable (`x` para coordenadas horizontales, `i` para índices...), pero variables como `f` para cantidad de elementos, `r` para el resultado de restar dos números, `b` para sumatorio de números positivos, `c` para sumatorio de números negativos y `e` para comprobar si un número es par o impar es una elección de nombres nefasta y contraintuitiva.
- No declares variables que no necesitas: declaras `a` y `d` para no usarlas, además declaras variables que sólo usas para almacenar el resultado de una expresión cuyo resultado después usas para tomar una decisión; podrías usar la expresión directamente sin crear la variable.
- Reduce el ámbito de las variables: en versiones antiguas de [c](/questions/tagged/c), era necesario declarar las variables al inicio de los ámbitos. Hoy día no es necesario y se aconseja que la declaración de variables esté esté lo más cerca posible de su lugar de uso, lo cuál facilita entender su cometido y entender el código en su conjunto.
- Reduce la cantidad de llamadas a `printf`: Cada llamada a función tiene un coste adicional a la llamada e si, debe cambiar el ámbito la pila local. Si puedes hacer más cosas con menos llamadas, el código funcionará de manera más eficiente.
- He usado un `for`, no un `do`-`while`: el bucle `for` combina con la mínima cantidad de código escrito una variable de control de ámbito acotado, un incremento y una condición de salida.

Con los consejos anteriores, el código en total podría parecerse a:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int cantidad = 10;
    int indice = 0;
    int *numeros = (int*)malloc(cantidad);

    for (int numero = 1; numero; ++indice)
    {
        if (indice == cantidad)
        {
            numeros = (int*)realloc(numeros, cantidad *= 2);
        }

        printf("Dame un numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero);
        numeros[indice] = numero;
    }

    int positivos = 0, negativos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i != indice; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", numeros[i], (numeros[i] % 2) ? "impar" : "par");

        if (numeros[i] < 0)
            negativos += numeros[i];
        else
            positivos += numeros[i];
    }

    printf("Suma de positivos: %d\n"
        "Suma de negativos: %d\n"
        "Diferencia %d", positivos, negativos, positivos - negativos);
    return 0;
}
```